# Enable "break on error" with xDebug in PHPStorm

Tags: xdebug, phpstorm

I can debug with xDebug in PHPStorm by setting breakpoints.
But I really want to jump back into IDE when runtime error has occurred (e.g. null reference).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is now. The feature was just added to PhpStorm 7.1 release.

Blog entry with details:
http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/12/just-in-time-debugging-and-php-exception-breakpoints-with-phpstorm-and-xdebug/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like 'xdebug.remote_mode=jit'(http://xdebug.org/docs/remote#remote_mode) configuration option will do that. I tested it with the latest PhpStorm release(2.1.3) and found that it isn't supported. Please vote - http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-7353